# How can I change a variable value using button/slider/touch action?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a student and very new to coding (Xcode with Swift language in this case).
I was trying to change a variable using a button/slider/gesture like this:

There are two variables (firstVariable & secondVariable) and set up a UIslider input that should define the value of the variables
I wanted the variables to be the same value of the slider/touchgesture but the variables remain 4 and 6 even after scrolling the slider in the simulator.
I think its because they are out of the scope of the slider function but how can I link them?

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var firstVariable = 4
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var secondVariable = 6
        print(secondVariable)
        print(firstVariable)
        let myslider = UISlider()

        //create a UISLider
        myslider.maximumValue = 100
        myslider.minimumValue = 0
        myslider.value = 30
        myslider.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 40)
        myslider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderinput), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(myslider)
    }
    
    @objc func sliderinput(sender: UISlider) {
        
        firstVariable = Int(sender.value)
        secondVariable = Int(sender.value)
    }
    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you checking the values of firstVariable and secondVariable?  And is this the actual code you're running?  Because you're accessing `secondVariable` in the `sliderInput(sender: UISlider)` but the var is out of scope, so this shouldn't compile.

Comment: Sorry @clawesome that wasn’t the actual code, I just posted the actual context in down here and maybe it makes more sense now :D sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take your `secondVariable` outside of the viewDidLoad as you cannot access it outside of viewDidLoad. To learn about `scope` read [this](https://learnappmaking.com/scope-context-swift-how-to/). And you need to print the value of the variables to see the values are actually changing.

```
@objc func sliderinput(sender: UISlider) {
    firstVariable = Int(sender.value)
    secondVariable = Int(sender.value)
    print(secondVariable)
    print(firstVariable)
}
```

Comment: Yes, its True. But if we use “firstVariable” as the Y coordinates of a triangle shape UIBezierpath so whenever we used the slider, the shape would move up and down on the screen. I simplified the context for easy understanding, the real context its like 100 lines of code, I can post it here.

Comment: Like this:
`let trianglepath = UIBezierPath()`
`trianglepath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: firstVariable))`
`trianglepath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 20))`
`trianglepath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 120))`
`trianglepath.close()`

Comment: A triangle in which a vertex moves Y up and down

Comment: In how many line 'firstVariable' is used? Here you used just once. 
Anyway do you want something like [this](https://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWujpBGqxfQ)

Comment: have you checked both the links?

Comment: Yeah, the second link seems interesting, @Zulqarnayn, thank you! I spent hours looking for a video like that but didn’t find anything similar. 
I posted the real context down below anyway

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is the real context. I wanted to make an infinite timeline like the iOS calendar day tab or like a video editing software timeline for example.
I haven’t yet figured out how to get the distance from the beginning and end of the touch and how to link it to the scrollDistance variable on the beginning so I could create a scroll down effect and later a pinchgesturerecognizer to set the spacing/zoom between the lines.
I know I could use a UIscrollview or UIcollectionview but I felt it was good idea to create a custom one xD
Once again thanks for everyones support! :D

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let lineElements: Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    let spacing: Int = 30  //spacing between elements
    var scrollDistance = 90  // 90 for example, this should be the pangesture distance
    
    //UIPanGestureRecogn function to determine the Y scroll distance from touch began to ended
    @objc func touchinput (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let touchlocation = sender.location(in: view)
        var touchStart: CGPoint
        var touchEnd: CGPoint
        print("touch current location is", touchlocation)
        
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            touchStart = sender.location(in: view)
            print("touch start", touchStart)
        } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            touchEnd = sender.location(in: view)
            print("touch end", touchEnd)
        }
        //I haven’t figure out how to get the distance between start and end and link it to the scrollDistance
        //let scrollDistance = touchEnd.y - touchStart.y
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ===================== Timeline a partir daqui =========================
        let totalElements: Int = lineElements.count
        
        for n in 1...totalElements {
            
            let yPosition = lineElements[n - 1] * spacing + scrollDistance //Get Line heigh index times the spacing + scroll distance by touch pan gesture
            let hourlabel = UILabel()
            let linepath = UIBezierPath()
            
            linepath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: yPosition))
            linepath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 350, y: yPosition))
            linepath.lineWidth = 8
            let lineshape = CAShapeLayer()
            lineshape.path = linepath.cgPath
            lineshape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            lineshape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineshape)
            
            hourlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: yPosition - 20, width: 45, height: 40)
            hourlabel.text = "\(n):00"
            hourlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Claro", size: 12)
            hourlabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
            hourlabel.textAlignment = .right
            self.view.addSubview(hourlabel)
        }
        
        // ===== GESTURE =====
        let gesto = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        gesto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchinput))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesto)
    }
    
}
´´´
```

Comment: probably adding this inside/below question will be more helpful for people later.